# Open new page using if else statement to check to see if an html form element is equal to a certain word

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

How do I open new page using an if else statement to check to see if an html form element is equal to a certain word or phrase. Basically, I have a form and if the user types certain words or phrases (say John or Maria) into, say, the Name input, then I want to write an if, else statement to open a new page, but only when Name is filled out with John or Maria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="name" name="person" />

<script>
function opener() {
    var text = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var targetNames = {
        john : "http://example1",
        maria : "http://example2"
    };
    if (text in targetNames) {
        window.open(targetNames[text]);  
    }
}

document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', opener, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`<input id="name" name="person" />

<script>
function opener() {
    var text = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var targetNames = {
        john : "http://example1",
        maria : "http://example2"
    };
    if (text in targetNames) {
        window.open(targetNames[text]);  
    }
}

document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('keyup', opener, false);
</script>`
```

"I hope this helps!"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).